# Not able to pass object from controller to view page in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i m going to pass the "greetings" object from controller to view page but the output is coming as ${greetings} as it should appear "WELCOME TO SPRING". I have looked everywhere in my code but i am not getting what the wrong is. I have done this already before but getting this error for first time. Please someone help me.

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home","/index"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("greetings","WELCOME TO SPRING");
        return mv;
    }
```

page.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${greetings}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd


   ">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.ashwin.pasalstore.controller " />

   <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix">
                  <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
               </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>
        </bean>


   </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- configuring dispatcher-servlet -->
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
  <artifactId>pasalstore</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>pasalstore Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>pasalstore</finalName>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image: It is printing whatever is there in my page.jsp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `web.xml`, you declare it as `Servlet2.3`

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

Change it to `Servlet2.4` or higher,such as below:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="Your_WebApp_ID"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Your configuration codes-->

</web-app>
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5. pasalstore  line 1 Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

Comment: @KarkiAshwin If you want to use `EL expression` in your project,you must update your Servlet from `2.3` to `2.4` or higher,since `2.3` do not support `EL expression`

Comment: i understand and did whatyou said but i am getting the version mistmatch error

Comment: @KarkiAshwin you need to update your `pom.xml` to the correct version

Comment: plz brother help me i m stuck for 3days in these work. what should i upgrade in pom.xml?

Comment: this should fix the problem. I find no other problem with this.